# Creating .txt files from excel columns with description

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I am trying to create .txt files that have the following:

- Txt file name would be cell(A1)
- Content of the txt file needs to be the content of cell (B1)
- Repeat throughout the column
  I am new to VBA and would kindly appreciate your help. I tried some codes, but I am not familiar with troubleshooting on VBA, so not a lot of luck there.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].